# Creating a "Check Names" button in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am new to using VBA and Macros and am wondering if there is a way to add a "check names" function in Excel (similar to the function in Outlook).  Part of the form I am working on requires me to enter names of employees and I would like to be able to click a button to make sure I have spelled their names correctly and they are in our email system.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depending on how many names, you could use a list (hidden in your personal workbook?) in Excel and flag if not on that list using a For loop and an IF, or if there aren't many, you could write a CASE statement in VBA. Then you flag if they aren't on the 'approved' list

Comment: could you not design a outlook form querying data from centrally stored Excel? that way you have all outlook mail functions and  I believe this is much more realistic as querying outlook names require access grant on outlook (?)

Comment: Where do you need to check names? In the Outlook Address Book or AD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of answers here:

Edit:  Created in Excel 2010 (no idea if it'll work in 2003).

The first will return TRUE or FALSE if the name can be resolved in Outlook.

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP
' Author    : Sue Mosher - updated by D.Bartrup-Cook to work in Excel late binding.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function ResolveDisplayName(sFromName) As Boolean

    Dim OLApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim oRecip As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        ResolveDisplayName = True
    Else
        ResolveDisplayName = False
    End If

End Function
```

The second will resolve the name and return the email address:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP
' Author    : Sue Mosher - updated by D.Bartrup-Cook to work in Excel late binding.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(sFromName) As String
    Dim OLApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim oRecip As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        Select Case oRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
            Case 0, 5 'olExchangeUserAddressEntry & olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry
                Set oEU = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
                If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
                    ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            Case 10, 30 'olOutlookContactAddressEntry & 'olSmtpAddressEntry
                    ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oRecip.AddressEntry.Address
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

Here's a test procedure showing how to use both functions:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox ResolveDisplayName("Marty Moesta")
    MsgBox ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP("Marty Moesta")

End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve will not display ambiguous name dialog box.

Comment: I'd never even considered that @Dmitry - I'm going to have to work on that.  Found this link which may point me in the right direction - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb646055(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Yes, that is for selecting the names, not for ambiguous names.