# VBA - Convert Exchange Online Email Address as SMTP Address

Tags: vba, outlook, smtp

I get the exchange online addresses from users, but I want to convert or somehow get the SMTP Address of them.

I am not sure how to get the SMTP Address from Email1Address.

```
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objContactsFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set objItems = objContactsFolder.Items

For Each obj In objItems
    'Test for contact and not distribution list
    If obj.Class = olContact Then
        Set objContact = obj

      With objContact

      If .Email1Address <>"" Then
         'I want to add the SMTP-Address after the .LastNameAndFirstName of a User
          strFileAs = .LastNameAndFirstName

         .Email1DisplayName= strFileAs

         .Save
       End If
      End With
    End If

    Err.Clear
Next
```

Comment: what is the code that you have tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Search for `ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP` - code you're looking for is by Sue Mosher.

Comment: See [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/).

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161726/creating-a-check-names-button-in-excel.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for the email object, see if you can implement it:

```
dim email as string
If myItem.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
email = myItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
email = myItem.SenderEmailAdress
End If
```