# On Error GoTo optimization VBA

Tags: vba

```
Sub ComName_Click()
    Dim objOL As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    On Error GoTo 1

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(0)
        With objMail
            .To = [b3]
            .CC = [c3]
            .Body = [e3]
            .Subject = [d3] & " " & [h1]
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\File1.xlsx"
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\File2.xlsx"
            .display
        End With
    Exit Sub

1:

 Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(0)
        With objMail
            .To = [b3]
            .CC = [c3]
            .Body = [e3]
            .Subject = [d3] & " " & [h1]
            .display
        End With    
End Sub
```

Sometimes files are absent and I need create the letter without attachments. 
- Can I make the "1" part of code shorter?
- How can I upgrade the code in case if one of files "File1" or "File2" is absent, and system should attach only one of them which is available?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No need to jump to 1. Add the attachment only if the file exists. `If Len(Dir("C:\Users\File1.xlsx")) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\File1.xlsx"`

Comment: Or if you want to add all files in a certain folder just loop through that folder:  `For each file in folder: .Attachments.Add file: Next file`.  Also if the code only errors when it tries to attach a non-existent file then the email and addresses from the first block of code would still exist.

Comment: @Kostas K. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @KostaK said - check if the file exists before adding it.

I've used the `FileSystemObject` in this example, but `Dir` also does it.

```
Public Sub ComNamne_Click()

    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim objFSO As Object

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim vAttachments As Variant
    Dim vFile As Variant

    On Error GoTo Err_Handle

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    vAttachments = Array("C:\Users\File1.xlsx", _
                         "C:\Users\File2.xlsx")

    Set objMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    With objMail
        .Display
        .To = wrkSht.Range("B3")
        .CC = wrkSht.Range("C3")
        .Body = wrkSht.Range("E3")
        .Subject = wrkSht.Range("D3") & " " & wrkSht.Range("H1")
        For Each vFile In vAttachments
            If objFSO.FileExists(vFile) Then
                .Attachments.Add vFile
            End If
        Next vFile
    End With

FastExit:
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set wrkSht = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing

Exit Sub

Err_Handle:
    Select Case Err.Number

        'case ???  Handle any errors you may expect.

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Unhandled error!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Resume FastExit
    End Select

End Sub
```

If the email addresses are internal to your organisation then `ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP` by Sue Mosher may come in handy:  [Creating a "Check Names" button in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161726/creating-a-check-names-button-in-excel)