# How to capture the user's Outlook email address?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a VBA function in Excel to identify the current user's email address.

```vb
Public Function UserName()

Dim OL, olAllUsers, oExchUser, oentry, myitem As Object
Dim User As String

Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olAllUsers = OL.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries

User = OL.Session.CurrentUser.Name

Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(User)

Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()

UserName = oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

End Function
```

For most users, this spits out their email address (e.g. john_doe@generic.com).

For some it doesn't update away from the default, which is my own email as the code executed successfully when I tried it.

Comment: If the Address Entry is either already an SMTP address or a distribution list then the GetExchangeUser won't fetch properly. Some of the answers here may help although it would need to be ported to Excel code from Outlook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641704/how-do-you-extract-email-addresses-from-the-to-field-in-outlook/66484483#66484483

Comment: One of the links seem to have an Excel based answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161726/creating-a-check-names-button-in-excel

Comment: Yes, it looks like that was exactly the issue. I tried a model using the Account.SmtpAddress protocol in one of the comments and it appears to be working perfectly for all impacted users. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Account.SmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account.smtpaddress?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm743);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property for getting the SMTP email address. It returns a string representing the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `Account`.

```
Dim UserMailAddress As String
Set UserMailAddress = OL.Session.CurrentUser.SmtpAddress
```

In case if you get an Exchange-like email address you may convert it to the SMTP one. See [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, it looks like isolating the SMTP email address was what I needed to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is constant for all the users, lets say gmail.com is constant. And user_name of system is the user_id then you can try something like this.

```
Dim User As String
user = environ("Username")
email = user & "gmail.com"
```