# Grab sender email address instead of Name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that opens a specific email, grabs the reply to email address, closes that email, then creates a new email with the To as the sender email address of the previous email.

Sometimes the address comes over as the name and not the full `xxxx@xxx.com`.

`Filename` below is the email that is on my shared drive. Address is the variable where I want to store all of the email addresses, the 'Reply All'.

```vb
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set outEmail = OutApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(Filename)
With outEmail.ReplyAll
    .display
    Address = .to
    .Close olDiscard
    Set outEmail = Nothing
End With
```

Comment: The code by Sue Mosher in my answer to [Creating a "Check Names" button in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161726/creating-a-check-names-button-in-excel/31161938#31161938) might work for you.

Comment: You may find the following useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484483/3688861

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Recipients` property instead of the string `To` field which may contain the name of the sender, not the actual email address. Use `Recipients(index)`, where index is the name or index number, to return a single `Recipient` object. The name can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The [Recipient.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) returns or sets a long representing the type of recipient. For the `MailItem` a recipient can have one of the following `OlMailRecipientType` constants: `olBCC`, `olCC`, `olOriginator`, or `olTo`. So, iteraring over all recipients and checking the `Type` property value you can find the `To` recipients.

```
 For d = 1 To myItem.Recipients.count 
   Debug.Print myItem.Recipients.item(d).name 
   Debug.Print myItem.Recipients.item(d).Type 
 Next
```

Finally, you can use all properties of the `Recipient` object to get the email address such as [Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) or just set up the new email with the same object by using the [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method which creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. It accepts a *string* which represents the name of the recipient representing the display *name*, the *alias*, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

Note, you can get the *Sender* related properties from the original item without creating a reply-all draft item.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please provide an example as I am unfamiliar with the syntax to do the above. I understand the concept, just dont know how to format the code.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to create / display / close a reply just to figure out who the message sender is. Use `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` or `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser()` (in case of an Exchange address):

```
Set outEmail = OutApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(Filename)
if outEmail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
  Address = outEmail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySMTPAddress
Else
  Address = outEmail.SenderEmailAddress 
End If
```

If you need all recipients in an email, loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and extract addresses from the `Recipient.Address` property or use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySMTPAddress`. Make sure to exclude the current user:

Off the top of my head:

```
for each recip in outEmail.Recipients
  set addEntry = recip.AddressEntry
  if addEntry.Type = "EX" Then
    Addresses = Addresses & ";" & addEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySMTPAddress
  Else
    Addresses = Addresses & ";" & addEntry.Address
  End If
next
```

Comment: Thank you for the above. This works but only gives me the sender, not any additional emails (i want to do a reply all basically)

Comment: See the updated answer above