# Resolve Outlook email addresses from names using Excel VBA: Error 287

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an VBA script that loops through a spreadsheet and finds employees that are not assigned and sends that employee and email.

I have had a list of email addresses (Outlook GAL) that works. As the list grows I have been trying to pull the email address from Outlook by referencing the name from the loop.

I found this code online:

```vb
Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(sFromName) As String
    ' takes a Display Name (i.e. "James Smith") and turns it into an email address (james.smith@myco.com)
    ' necessary because the Outlook address is a long, convoluted string when the email is going to someone in the organization.
    ' source:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161726/creating-a-check-names-button-in-excel

    Dim OLApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim oRecip As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        Select Case oRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
            Case 0, 5 'olExchangeUserAddressEntry & olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry
                Set oEU = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
                If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
                    ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            Case 10, 30 'olOutlookContactAddressEntry & 'olSmtpAddressEntry
                Dim PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String
                PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
                ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oRecip.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

On the line `oRecip.Resolve` I get

> "Run-time error 287" Application-defined or object-defined error".

I have seen it may be a security permission but I can't find a setting that would be causing it and have VBA creating and sending emails from other scripts.

How do I resolve this error?

Is there another way to find company Outlook email addresses from first and last names?

Comment: Does it happen with all names or just some?

Comment: Unless Outlook VBA is locked down, consider starting in Outlook rather than Excel.