# What is the value returned by mailItem.Recipients[i].Address represent?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

As per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/deva/outlook-programming-how-to-get-the-smtp-address-of-the-sender-of-a-mail-item-using-outlook-object-model) mailItem.Recipients[i].Address returns something like the below:

```
/O=MFC2013/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=B370134F8FFD4CF3A0023F27B6B61F7D-ADMINISTRATOR
```

What are those values and how and where are they configured?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you extract email addresses from the 'To' field in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641704/how-do-you-extract-email-addresses-from-the-to-field-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Exchange Server can operate with email address types such as Exchange, SMTP, X.400, Microsoft Mail, etc. By default, the `Address` property of the `Mail.Recipient` object returns just an Exchange type address, for example, this one:

```
/O=MFC2013/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=B370134F8FFD4CF3A0023F27B6B61F7D-ADMINISTRATOR
```

To retrieve the SMTP address, use the following sequence of calls:

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Theoretically, to get other address types, we need to find the recipient in the Outlook address book by using the `IAddrBook.ResolveName` method, then reach the `IMailUser` interface with the `IAddrBook.OpenEntry` method and get the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` property.

```
Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(sFromName)
  Dim oRecip As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim oEU As Outlook.ExchangeUser
  Dim oEDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

  Set oRecip = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
  oRecip.Resolve
  If oRecip.Resolved Then
    Select Case oRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
      Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
        Set oEU = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
          ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress + vbCrLf + oEU.BusinessTelephoneNumber
        End If
      Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry
        Set oEU = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
          ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress + vbCrLf + oEU.BusinessTelephoneNumber
        End If
      Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
        Set oEDL = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
        If Not (oEDL Is Nothing) Then
          ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress + vbCrLf + oEU.BusinessTelephoneNumber
        End If
    End Select
  End If
End Function  ' ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP
```